# Plone 3.3 -> 4 migration: setup_tool.setImportContext() missing

Tags: plone

I am updating some old products to 4.x codebase.

This is common pattern in old Install.py:

```
def install(self):
    out=StringIO()

    # Install CSS, JS and other GenericProfile stuff
    setup_tool = getToolByName(self, 'portal_setup')
    original_context = setup_tool.getImportContextID()
    setup_tool.setImportContext('profile-Products.NoneMultiSelectionWidget:default')
    setup_tool.runAllImportSteps()
```

However, setup_tool.setImportContext() method no longer exist. What would be the correct replacement code? Do I need replacement code or are GenericSetup XML files automatically picked up?

The traceback:

```
  - __traceback_info__: ('Products.NoneMultiSelectionWidget',)
     File "/Users/moo/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ExternalMethod-2.13.0-py2.6.egg/Products/ExternalMethod/ExternalMethod.py", line 234, in __call__
       return f(*args, **kw)
      - __traceback_info__: ((<PloneSite at /plone>,), {}, None)
     File "/Users/moo/code/x/src/x/Products.NoneMultiSelectionWidget/Products/NoneMultiSelectionWidget/Extensions/Install.py", line 19, in install
       setup_tool.setImportContext('profile-Products.NoneMultiSelectionWidget:default')
   AttributeError: setImportContext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think setImportContext was already deprecated in Plone 3, but I am not sure about that.  Anyway, the import context should not explicitly be set anymore, so instead of this:

```
setup_tool = getToolByName(self, 'portal_setup')
original_context = setup_tool.getImportContextID()
setup_tool.setImportContext('profilename')
setup_tool.runAllImportSteps()
# ... restore original context ...
```

it is now simply this:

```
setup_tool = getToolByName(self, 'portal_setup')
setup_tool.runAllImportStepsFromProfile('profilename')
```

Also, as long as your package only has one GS profile, you do not need this Extensions/install.py code at all, as the profile will get picked up automatically.